# Running and monitoring Java on an EC2 instance

Tags: java, ssh, amazon-ec2, cloud

I'm currently working on my first deployment of a large server side application which is written in Java. There is continuous console output which I would like to occasionally monitor and verify that is running, and ideally receive an alert if it crashes for whatever reason.

If I SSH into the server and execute the executable and then logout of that session, I believe it terminates that executable. How then, do I launch the executable and allow it to run even if my client computer isn't logged in 24/7? Will I be able to tap into the executable's output when I *do* want to see it?

I have a basic alert set through AWS that will alert me if network traffic drops below 2kb/s. What else can I set up besides that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to do with AWS. You can assume your EC2 instance as remote machine. If it's Unix based machine. It's simple. SSH to your machine and...

1. Run your executable as

   ```
   sudo nohup /path/to/my/exec > /path/to/log/file.log &
   ```
2. If you ever want to see the output SSH to the machine and use `vi`

   ```
   vi /path/to/log/file.log
   ```

   to see running log use `tail`

   ```
   tail -f /path/to/log/file.log
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use screen (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or Byobu (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byobu_%28software%29) to allow a process to continue to run while you log out. You can reconnect to the session when you log back in. You can Google for a tutorial on the one you choose; there are many.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, your best bet is to use `nohup` ([here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)). It allows to run a command, exit and see the output of a process in a `nohup.log` file.

And since it is a standard command, it is already available on any linux distro (no need to install anything).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above post. If your server is a Linux machine you can always do execute nohup commandname.sh & this will append your execution logs to nohup log. Hence, you can close the console and log in back any time and go to the location of the nohup file and see tail -f nohup.out.